# script to replace a set of strings in a set of files

Tags: perl, shell

for a set of java files available in myfolder, I would like to replace :

```
ColorTee.testh = new TestH(A,"JavaFileName".class);
ColorTee.testh.addFile(C,"/folder1/folder2/folder3/file","myFile")
```

With:

```
ColorTee.testh = new TestH(Z,A,"JavaFileName".class);
ColorTee.testh.addFile(C,/folder3/file,"myfile");
```

knowing that "myfile" is different from a file to another

and add `import com.soft.test.event;` just after

```
import java.io.File;
```

and tried :

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.java
do
  echo 
  sed -i -e "" "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, I don't know if there is an error in post but /folder3/file seems not to be valid in java

```
perl -i.bak -pe '
    s/ColorTee\.testh = new TestH\(A,B\);/ColorTee.testh = new TestH(Z,A,F);/;
    s^ColorTee\.testh\.addFile\(C,"/folder1/folder2/folder3/file","myFile"\)^ColorTee.testh.addFile(C,/folder3/file,"myfile");^;
    s/import java.io.File;/import java.io.File;\nimport com.soft.test.event;/;
  ' *.java
```

-i.bak => will backup original file in *.java.bak remove .bak in command to disable backup

Answer (score 1):

use the follow shell command to replace it.I don't know if your pattern remains the same all the way.you can change the replace part as you will.

to replace a pattern with replacement string:

```
sed -e s/repexpr/replacement string/ "$file".bak >> "$file";
```

for adding the newline you can use

```
sed '/import java.io.File;/a\import com.soft.test.event;' "$file"
```

it's like.

```
for file in *.java
do  
    mv "$file" "$file".bak
    sed -e s/TestH\(A/TestH\(Z,A/ "$file".bak >> "$file"
    mv "$file" "$file".bak
    sed '/import java.io.File;/a\import com.soft.test.event;' "$file".bak >> "$file"
    rm  "$file".bak
done
```

sorry but i don't know how to work with multi-line replacement.
You may do it twice.

Comment: oyss , when I execute the script , I got : mv: cannot stat `*.java': No such file or directory                                                 
sed: -e expression #1, char 83: unterminated `s' command

Comment: I've test the code in linux and it is ok.what os your use? might be parsing problem?what a about try it with single step.Or do a little debug on it.Echo the "$file" to check the fileanme.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular difficulty:

```
for file in *.java
do
    sed -i.bak -e \
    "s#import java.io.File;#import java.io.File;\nimport com.soft.test.event;#;s#ColorTee.testh = new TestH(A,\"JavaFileName\".class);#ColorTee.testh = new TestH(Z,A,\"JavaFileName\".class);#g;s#ColorTee.testh.addFile(C,\"/folder1/folder2/folder3/file\",\"myFile\")#ColorTee.testh.addFile(C,/folder3/file,\"$file\");#g" "$file"    
done
```

Comment: I don't want to replace all strings as in all java files the name of "myFile" isn't the same

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

my $dir = 'myfolder';
opendir my $dh, $dir or die $!;
my @files = map "$dir/$_", grep /.java$/, readdir $dh;

my @lines = (
  'ColorTee.testh = new TestH',
  'ColorTee.testh.addFile',
  'import java.io.File',
);
do { s/\s+/\\s+/g; s/\./\\./g; } for @lines;

for my $file (@files) {

  tie my @text, 'Tie::File', $file or die $!;

  for (my $i = 0; $i < $#text; $i++) {

    if ($text[$i] =~ /$lines[0]/ and $text[$i+1] =~ /$lines[1]/) {
      $text[$i] =~ s/\(A,\s*"JavaFileName"/(Z,A,"JavaFileName"/;
      $text[$i+1] =~ s|folder1/folder2/folder3/|folder3/|;
      $i += 2;
    }
    elsif ($text[$i] =~ /$lines[2]/) {
      splice @text, $i+1, 0, 'import com.soft.test.event;';
      $i += 1;
    }
  }

  untie @text;
  print "$file updated\n";
}
```

Comment: hey bordin , juste a question : folder3 isn't the same for all files the name of folder 3 changes so how could I say let the path from folder3